# DataGridView.Invoke freezes

Tags: c#, datagridview, thread-safety, invoke

I have an Action delegate:

```
public static Action SubscribeForTable;
```

I loaded it with my `Objects` method

```
public void SubscribeMe()
{
    Parallel.For(0, ACCESS.GetAppCount(), AppCheck);
    CheckTable(true);
}
```

So I have a delegate, which contains the same function but for different objects.

Then I do this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(SubscribeForTable);
```

So it launched to run, and I wait...I wait...and nothing happens! The application is stuck! Then I started my debugger.

return to `SubscribeMe()` function

```
Parallel.For(0, ACCESS.GetAppCount(), AppCheck); //OK
CheckTable(true);  // lets see what is in
```

Then I looked to this function..

```
delegate void CheckTableCallback(bool check);

private void CheckTable(bool Subscribed)
{
    if (DataGridView1.InvokeRequired) // OK
    {
        CheckTableCallback Safe = new CheckTableCallback(CheckTable);  // OK
        DataGridView1.Invoke(Safe, new Object[] {Subscribed}); //HANGS HERE!
    }
    else
    {
        ....
```

So it hangs on `DataGridView.Invoke`. Why so? Hope I have explained my problem correctly.

Comment: Using Invoke() is apt to cause deadlock, always favor BeginInvoke().  This deadlock is caused by the UI thread being busy, typically waiting for the worker thread to complete.   It should not wait.  Use Debug + Windows + Threads to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Control.Invoke`, by design, blocks the current thread until the UI thread can process messages.

If you're calling your `Parallel.For` loop from the UI thread, that will block the UI thread until it completes.

The two cause a condition where one operation (the `Invoke` call) can't finish until the other completes and free's up the UI thread (`Parallel.For`), but the second can't complete until the individual work items finish.

You may be able to use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` to avoid the dead lock here, if you're just updating the UI.  This will cause the actual method (`CheckTable`) to run and set the values *after* the entire operation completes.